# Typescript Generic type Error : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

The purpose of the code is to create a custom hook for the input tag.
I wanted to use a generic type in this custom hook.
The type of InputReturn is pasted from vscode.
At this time, an error occurs in setValue in the handler function.
" Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction' "
please, how can i fix it?

```
type InputReturn<T> = readonly [
  T,
  (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>,
];

export function useInput<T>(initialValue: T): InputReturn<T> {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handler = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY34l.png)    setValue(e.target.value);
  }, []);
  return [value, handler, setValue] as const;
}
```

At first, I want change union type "string | number" to generic type.
Here is the code before the introduction of generic types:

```
export function useInput(initialValue: string | number) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handler = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }, []);
  return [value, handler, setValue] as const;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be generic? Since the `e.target.value` will always be a string regardless of the type of input.

Comment: then, Would this code be a more appropriate usage? In fact, I'm not good at typescript, so I misjudged the introduction of generics.

Comment: ```
type InputReturn = readonly [
  string | number,
  (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>,
];

export const useInput = (initialValue: string | number): InputReturn => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const handler = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }, []);
  return [value, handler, setValue] as const;
};
```